# What is the length between the charge inside a wire and a measuring point within the wire?

Tags: electric-fields, charge

I have a finite wire of length $a$, and I am to find the electric field at a point inside the wire. I looked at this site [Hyper Physics: Electric Field Line of Charge](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/elelin.html), and I thought maybe it was promising. However I'm confused as to how I can find the electric field along the x-axis rather than the z-axis because I'm not trying to find the electric field at a point outside of the wire, I need to find it inside. I tried to follow their logic and got this:

I set my origin to be in the center, and the wire extends to ${-a\over 2}$ to ${a\over 2}$ on either side. My point of measurement is on the z-axis.

$$r=\sqrt{x^2+z^2} \ ; \ k={1\over 4\pi\epsilon_0} \ ; \ x=z\tan\theta$$
$$dE_z={k\lambda\over r^2}dx{z\over r} \ ; \ x^2+z^2=z^2(1+tan^2\ \theta) \ ; \ dE_z=z^2\sec^2\theta$$

$$E_z={k\lambda z}\int{z \sec^2\theta\over (z^2\sec^2\theta)(z\sec\theta)}d\theta=k\lambda z \int\cos\theta d\theta={k\lambda\over z}\sin\theta$$

Plug x back in and solve for limits ${-a\over 2}$ to ${a\over 2}$:
$$E_z={k\lambda\over z}\Big({x\over \sqrt{x^2+z^2}}\Big) = {k\lambda\over z}\Big({{a\over 2}-({-a\over 2})\over \sqrt{x^2+z^2}}\Big) = {k\lambda\over z}\Big({a\over \sqrt{{a^2\over 4}+z^2}}\Big) $$

But this is for the electric field along the z-axis, isn't it? I don't understand how I use this to find the electric field at a point *within* the finite wire. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you linked to is for a line charge. That is, the wire has no spatial extent in the radial direction. So it doesn't really make sense to talk about the electric field *inside* of it.

Comment: Right, that makes sense to me. I'm confused as to what $r$ needs to be in my Coulomb equation. I've tried two different scenarios, one where the measuring point is past the charge $dq$, and where it's before the point $dq$, this gives me answers that are opposite in sign. I'm not sure how to decide what the length needs to be.

Comment: You're using $dE_z $ instead of $dE_x $. Replace the $z $ there with $x $. And the $z^2$ in your distance with $0$.